# Handling HTML Markup in XML during ASP.Net DeSerialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, xml-serialization

I am working on a asp.net MVC 3 web application that displays data it collects from a XML web service. I have defined objects representing the entities in the XML and instead of manual parsing I am de-serializing the XML response into the corresponding object type.

My problem is that data returned in the web service contains HTML markup within some attributes.

```
<directions>
Take a left <br/> now take right <br/>
</directions>
```

notice the `<br/>` above, this causes the deserializer to fail. just fyi, getting the big web service provider to fix this issue is beyond the scope of this mere developer.

Would really appreciate any help/suggestions to gracefully tackle this situation. I don't want to resort to manual parsing for effort/efficiency reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surround the HTML in CDATA tags

```
<![CDATA[Take a left <br /> now take a right <br />]]>
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGeekYouNeed. Although its best to solve the problem at its source, this change will be have to be done at the web service level and I don't think I can get that done. I have to figure out a way to work with the data on my end.

Comment: On second thoughts I am thinking if it would be ok for me to capture the response in the string and then modify the tags with illegal data. Something like:Response.replace("<Directions>", "<Directions><![CDATA[");
Response.replace("</Directions>", "]]></Directions>");

Comment: I can't control the XML (can't add the CDATA). Is there any other way?